# BibLaTeX bibliography not displayed at all

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, report

I have a lot of problems with the bibliography.

I read the BibLaTeX manual but I couldn't find a way to fix it.

Here is the source:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\noindent\hrulefill

\section{foo}
\cite{1tree} \& \cite{wiki1}

\noindent\hrulefill

\printbibliography

\noindent\hrulefill

\end{document}
```

And here is my biblio.bib:

```
@misc{wiki1,
author = {Wikipedia},
title = {Disuguaglianza Triangolare},
year ={2015},
url ={https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disuguaglianza_triangolare},
} 

@online{1tree,
author = {Universit\`a di Torino},
title = {Definizione 1-Tree, TSP Lower Bound},
date = {date},
url = {http://www.di.unito.it/~locatell/didattica/ro2/TSPnewbound-sl.pdf},
}
```

And this is the output:

[image: Foo]

I would also be able to use

```
\defbibfilter{online}{ type=online }
\defbibfilter{offline}{ not type=online }
```

and

```
\printbibliography[filter=online]
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I am using TeXStudio with MikTeX

Comment: Did you run biber? What is the content of the `.blg` file?

Comment: If no `blg` file exists: [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154767)

Comment: Well, I feel a little bit stupid...I formatted my PC a few weeks ago and forgot to resetup TeX Studio with Biber.. Thanks everyone

Comment: The code (when put together) works perfectly fine here. Are you sure the Biber run completed successfully and all relevant programmes were run sufficiently often? See [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). Note that with your current definitions of the bibfilters, you could just use `\printbibliography[type=online]` and `\printbibliography[nottype=online]`.

Comment: Does that mean we can close your question as a duplicate of [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154767).

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be due to the `date` format, which should be `yyyy-mm-dd`. With this format it compiles fine, and the filters work. Don't forget to follow the cycle: `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex ->pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass[italian]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{somebiblio.bib}
\defbibfilter{online}{type=online }
\defbibfilter{offline}{not type=online }

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\noindent\hrulefill

\section{foo}
\cite{1tree} \& \cite{wiki1}

\noindent\hrulefill

\printbibliography[filter =online]

\printbibliography[filter =offline]

\noindent\hrulefill

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mhh, with a current Biber invalid date formats are simply ignored. Biber issues a warning about that, but the rest goes through.

Comment: You're right. Anyway, I posted  before the O.P. explained what really happened. I guess I should withdraw my answer.

Comment: I think this question should be closed since it was about a mis-configuration anyway. Your observation is certainly valid so you might as well let it stand.